# Define program which will interpret integers as coordinates on the number axis

Tags: java

How I can rewrite the program with `bitwise operators (it's MANDATORY)` instead of `if` statements, which will interpret as coordinates on the number axis of end points of two intervals: A = [a1, a2] and B = [b1, b2]. The program reads from the user one number (say, x) of type int and prints whether it is true that

```
• x ∈ A
• x ∈ B
• x ∈ A \ B
• x ∈ B \ A
• x ∈ A ∩ B
• x ∈ A ∪ B
  x in sym. diff of A and B
```

For example, if the defined intervals are A = [2, 4] and B = [1, 6] and the number
read is x = 5, the program should print something like:

```
Interval A = [2, 4]
Interval B = [1, 6]
Enter x 5
x in A: false
x in B: true
x in A\B: false
x in B\A: true
x in intersection of A and B: false
x in union of A and B: true
x in symm. diff. of A and B: true
```

So this is the given code and I have to rebuild it from code with `if` into code with `bitwise operators`

```
package com.company;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("input a1: ");
        int a1 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("input a2: ");
        int a2 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("input b1: ");
        int b1 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("input b2: ");
        int b2 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("input x: ");
        int x = sc.nextInt();

        int arr1[] = new int [...];
        int arr2[] = new int [...];

        for (int i = 0, j = a1; j <= a2; i++, j++) {
            arr1[i] = j;
        }
        for (int i = 0, j = b1; j <= b2; i++, j++) {
            arr2[i] = j;
        }

        System.out.println("Interval A: [" + a1 + ", " + a2 + "]");
        System.out.println("Interval B: [" + b1 + ", " + b2 + "]");
        System.out.println("Enter x: " + x);
        System.out.println("x in A: " + Exist(arr1, x));
        System.out.println("x in B: " + Exist(arr2, x));
        System.out.println("x in A/B: " + Relative_Complement(arr1, arr2, x));
        System.out.println("x in B/A: " + Relative_Complement(arr2, arr1, x));
        System.out.println("x in intersection of A and B: " + Intersection(arr1,arr2, x));
        System.out.println("x is union of A and B: " + Union(arr1, arr2, x));
    }

    static boolean Exist(int arr[], int x){
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(x == arr[i])
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    static boolean Relative_Complement(int arr1[], int arr2[], int x){
        int arr3[] = new int [arr1.length + arr2.length + 1];
        int arr4[] = new int [arr1.length + arr2.length + 1];

        for (int k = 0, i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
                if(arr2[i] == arr1[j]){
                    arr3[k++] = arr2[i];
                }
            }
        }

        for (int p = 0, j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
            if(!Exist(arr3, arr1[j])){
                arr4[p++] = arr1[j];
            }
        }

        return Exist(arr4, x);
    }

    static boolean Union(int arr1[], int arr2[], int x){
        int arr3[] = new int [arr1.length + arr2.length];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++, k++)
            arr3[k] = arr1[i];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++, k++)
            arr3[k] = arr2[i];

        return Exist(arr3, x);
    }

    static boolean Intersection(int arr1[], int arr2[], int x){
        int arr3[] = new int [arr1.length + arr2.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
                if(arr2[i] == arr1[j]){
                    arr3[i] = arr2[i];
                }
            }
        }

        return Exist(arr3, x);
    }
}
```